# How to write mongocxx (v3) query with Date data type?

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I have a collection and I need to extract only most recent data based on field updateDate (with data type Date).
 I use c++ driver (mongocxx (v3) ).

```
mongocxx::cursor cursor = 
    collection.find(document{} << "updateDate" << 
                    open_document << "$gt" << 
                    (date parameter)  << close_document <<
                    finalize); 

for(auto doc : cursor) { 
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << "\n"; 
}
```

How can I write my query for instance:
 what format, data type I need to pass as day?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB C++, How to add ISODate value when inserting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797650/mongodb-c-how-to-add-isodate-value-when-inserting)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

replace (date parameter) with `bsoncxx::types::b_date{<value>}`